# Добавление значений в три колонки openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Необходимо, чтобы значение добавлялось в каждую колонку, а не заменялось.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A'] = input('One: ') # Если использовать A1, то будет замена значения колонки A1
ws['B'] = input('Two: ')
ws['C'] = input('Three: ')
wb.save("123.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значения добавляются в колонку и не заменяется,а дополняется:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = '123.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet']
ddd = sheet_ranges['A1'].value
print(ddd)# смотрим изменения 
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = input('One: ')+'|'+ddd
wb.save("123.xlsx")
```

Значения добавляются значение добавлялось в A1,A2,A3 и так далее. до A15.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = '123.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet']
ddd = sheet_ranges['A1'].value
print(ddd)# смотрим изменения 
asd = input('1: ')+'|'+ddd
for row in range(1, 16):
    ws.cell(column=1, row=row, value=asd)
wb.save("123.xlsx")
```

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы введенное значение добавлялось в A2,A3 и так далее.

Comment: Прошу прощения за задержку и не правильно понятую задачу. Ответ поправил. Впредь обещаю не проявлять невнимательность при работе с вопросами.